# How to get focus to a new popup window which doesnt have name,id or unique title in selenium

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I want to get focus or select an window which pop-up's on click to the link and the link has following tags in html

```
<a target="_restaurant_50" href="/impersonate/50">View Dashboard</a>
```

if i put window name as _restaurant_50 it gives the following error in IDE

```
Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make sure to read http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows for potential workarounds.
```

How can i get the focus on this window please help...
I tried all the ways specified on net such as get all windows*, select by title but it gives the parent title only, webdriver PHP switch window, etc.

the number `50` is as per the number in database list.

I am using selenium with PHP.

Details:
Array Names before click
(
    [0] => selenium_main_app_window
)
Array Ids before Click
(
    [0] => undefined
)

Array Names After click
(
    [0] => selenium_main_app_window
)
Array Ids After click
(
    [0] => undefined
)E

**Update**:
I tried opening the url using openWindow("url",Windowname) which gets open on click. It worked but it opens a new page doesnt follow the logged in session it asks again for logging in
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was am able to do the above by following Steps.

we have
`<a target="_restaurant_50" href="/impersonate/50">View Dashboard</a>`

use
`as=getAttribute(//xpath@href)`

```
openWindow(as,MyWindow);
selectWindow("MyWindow");
windowFocus();
```

This also works for the dynamic links.

Thanks to ALL for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the PHP selenium drivers but the way I did this with Java was to get a list of Window Names (or IDs) before the click, perform the click, get the new list and select the window that wasn't there before.  Note that there is a selenium command to get all known window names and ids.

Also, if the issue is just that the number is generated from the database, you could get the target attribute from the link, and then use that to select the window it opens.

Comment: I tried the `selenium command to get all known window names and ids` but i am not getting the list it is generating blank variable, and for names/title it is giving only the parent window name/title where the focus is. Is there any other way and my all windows doesn't have window name or id.

Comment: Thanks for Reply I have updated the details as per your answer.